# Android, How get values from components generated dynamically in loop

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have create by a cycle, many components in my java.
And after (by a button) get all data, How can I do?

I have another problem in this Frame. When i change the value of seekbar, i like to get this value in textview (textViewSeekValue). But when i get this value it crash. Maybe because need a ID of TextView.

Like this (but in java)

```
<Linear Layout>
    <TextView></TextView>
    <Switch></Switch>
    <TextView></TextView>
    <Seekbar></Seekbatr>
</Linear Layout>
```

This is my code for generate the views

```
              for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
                        // LINEAR LAYOUT
                        LinearLayout layoutChild = new LinearLayout(context);
                        layoutChild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                    // Linear Layout - ID
                    layoutChild.setId(i);

                    // Linear Layout - Params
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    );
                    lp.setMargins(0,20,0,20);
                    layoutChild.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    layoutChild.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.TOP);

                    // TEXT VIEW - Label
                    final TextView textViewLabel = new TextView(context);
                    textViewLabel.setId(i);
                    textViewLabel.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textViewLabel.setTextSize(20);
                    textViewLabel.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    textViewLabel.setText(descr);

                    // SWITCH - flag
                    Switch switch_flag = new Switch(context);
                    switch_flag.setId(i);

                    // TEXT VIEW - SeekBar Value
                    final TextView textViewSeekValue = new TextView(context);
                    textViewSeekValue.setId(i);
                    textViewSeekValue.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textViewSeekValue.setTextSize(15);
                    textViewSeekValue.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

                    // SEEK BAR - slider
                    final SeekBar seekBar_slider = new SeekBar(context);
                    seekBar_slider.setId(i);
                    seekBar_slider.setMax(100);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_seekbar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    seekBar_slider.setLayoutParams(lp_seekbar);
                    seekBar_slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}

                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}

                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                            //textViewSeekValue.setText(arg1); // error
                            //error
                            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                            textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(textViewSeekValue.getId());
                            textView.setText(arg1); 

                        }
                    });

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ImageView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp_ImageView.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
                    imageViewSem.setLayoutParams(lp_ImageView);

                    layoutChild.addView(textViewLabel);

                    parentLayout.addView(layoutChild);
```

}

Comment: Attach the stacktrace

Comment: All your views have same Id `i` . You should start by assigning them unique Ids.